# Angular unit testing check if input is undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am unable to test else condition in my code as Unable to change value of input(). Please help.
Once I pass data in spec.ts unable to assign other data

````
@Input() data: any;
ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.data !== undefined) {
      this.fn1()
    }
    else {
      this fn2()
    }
  }```
````

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are calling `fixture.detectChanges` before you are setting `component.data`

```
it('populated data should do things and stuff', () => {
  // create your component, hopefully in the beforeEach
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // set the input BEFORE you call fixture.detectChanges the first time
  const data = {};
  component.data = data
 
  fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOnInit now fires

  // assert what you expect to happen
});
```

Test made as simple as possible. I'd prefer the approach where you use a fake TestHost that can pass the input to your component like it would when running. [Here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host) is the documentation around that. I gave an [example answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972500/angular-unit-test-how-to-mock-input-property-in-jasmin)